# Self-Hosted Web service no loading

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, self-hosting, asp.net-core-webapi

I am just trying to open and run one of my team projects and it is .NET Web API project which is configured to be self-hosted. To which configuration looks like following:

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:3434")
                .Build();

            host.Run();
```

- When it runs, it successfully launches a Console which says that service is listening at "http://0.0.0.0:3434". So far so good.
- Now, when I actually try to browse to that location then it does not load anything and throws a 404 on me
- I installed Fiddler from Telerik which helped a little bit so that it does not throw 404 anymore
  -However, it now throws a different error which looks like below:

> [Fiddler] The connection to '0.0.0.0' failed.  Error:
>   AddressNotAvailable (0x2741).  System.Net.Sockets.SocketException The
>   requested address is not valid in its context 0.0.0.0:3434

I am not sure what else to do. Any suggestions?

Comment: `0.0.0.0` means that it is binding to all IPs on your machine, you still need to establish the connection via a physical address. Try `http://127.0.0.1:3434`, and also `http://192.168.0.11` <- which would be your lan address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseUrls("http://*:3434")
            .Build();

host.Run();
```

Source Documentation [Introduction to hosting in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting#configuring-a-host)

> Server URLs `string`
>
> Key: `urls`. Set to a semicolon (`;`) separated list of URL prefixes to
>   which the server should respond. For example, `http://localhost:123`.
>   The domain/host name can be replaced with "`*`" to indicate the server
>   should listen to requests on any IP address or host using the
>   specified port and protocol (for example, `http://*:5000` or
>   `https://*:5001`). The protocol (`http://` or `https://`) must be included
>   with each URL. The prefixes are interpreted by the configured server;
>   supported formats will vary between servers.

```
new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseUrls("http://*:5000;http://localhost:5001;https://hostname:5002")
```

Once the host is up and running  now is a matter of making sure the controllers have the correct routes configured and that right URLs are called, otherwise a `404 Not Found` will be returned.

for example, the following controller

```
[Route("")]
public class RootController : Controller {
    [HttpGet] //Matches GET /
    public IActionResult Get() {
        return Ok("hello world");
    }

    [HttpGet("echo/{value}] //Matches GET /echo/anything-you-put-here
    public IActionResult GetEcho(string value) {
        return Ok(value);
    }
}
```

with the above host configuration should match the following URLs respectively

```
http://localhost:3434/

http://localhost:3434/echo/stack-overflow
```

Comment: Well, changing it to `* or for the matter of fact to localhost` starts throwing 404. Not sure what to do

Comment: @CoffeeBean now is a matter of making sure the controllers have the correct routes configured and that you are calling the right URL. DO you have a controller that handles the root URL?

Comment: ok so I found the problem. It was a little stupid on my side. Everything was set up correctly just that root directory did not have a default file like Index to load so I had to explicitly browse to URL/swagger.html and then it worked.

Comment: Your last comment was really helpful I really did not have a controller which handles the root URL